# Is there an HTML component for the time control of a media player?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on an webapp that needs to offer a time control for something media-like (it's not actual media, is an animation computed by the app). I'm thinking something like the red bar below youtube videos: it works like a progress bar, but it's also clickable, draggable, and can show information on hover (in a similar way that youtube offers a thumbnail and a timestamp).

I couldn't find any premade html/js component for that, the best I found are slider controls like https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider. Is there anything around that I can use, or should I just roll my own?

Answer (score 1):

Check this link, html5 video is your way:

http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/building-custom-controls-for-html5-videos

Also how to mod bars:

[is it possible to change default html5 video skin/color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467959/is-it-possible-to-change-default-html5-video-skin-color)

Comment: Can you please add the essence of the linked pages to the answer, as [explained in the help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), link-only answers are strongly discouraged and they routinely get deleted during reviews.